# Create a file to an application document folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to create a file in my application document folder and i have to store some content. That content takes from my localhost file. So i write a below code. But this code didn't create a file in my application document folder.

```
   - (void) createFile
    {
        NSString *strPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.5.117/~mac/banana.obj"];

        NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPath]];

        NSString *strLastpath = [strPath lastPathComponent];

        NSString *folderName = [@"Object File/" stringByAppendingString:strLastpath];

        NSLog(@"Path : %@ \n File Name : %@",strPath,folderName);

        NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

        databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName]];

        NSLog(@"Database Path : %@",databasePath);

        NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath] == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"File Exists");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"File not exists");
        }

        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data];

        [content writeToFile:strLastpath atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

    }
```

While build for running i got this.

```
2013-10-11 11:36:38.833 SampleFileCreation[1321:c07] Path : http://192.168.5.117/~mac/banana.obj 

File Name : Object File/banana.obj

2013-10-11 11:36:38.834 SampleFileCreation[1321:c07] Database Path : /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/4FA749DF-D12D-4956-AF76-140D2F981F17/Documents/Object File/banana.obj

2013-10-11 11:36:38.834 SampleFileCreation[1321:c07] File not exists
```

Comment: Are you sure NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPath]]; this is given you downloaded data?

Comment: Yes i got all that contents, i checked it using NSLog.

Comment: Which file type you going to download ??

Comment: @iAmbitious : Wavefront obj file. File extension is ".obj"

Comment: NSError *theError = nil;
                    [content writeToFile:strLastpath atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&theError];
            if(theError){
                NSLog(@"Tell Me error %@", [theError localizedDescription]);
            }
  Wrap up your code given line with NSError and tell what your debugger says.

Comment: Why you convert your file in NSString ???         [content writeToFile:strLastpath atomically:NO encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];  why you not directly write NSData in document directory ?

Comment: Why are you write this line NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",data]; You are converting it in wrong way. Use NSString *content =[[NSString alloc] initWithData: data];

Comment: @iAmbitious: i found the answer. i didn't not create a directory. i will post that code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
NSString *fileName = @"yourFileName";
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/fileName"];

NSDate *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:YourUrl]; // get date form url
[data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES]; // save data in file
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. File created successfully.

```
- (void) createFile {

    NSString *strPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://-.-.-.-/~mac/banana.obj"];        
    NSData *data =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPath]];            
    NSString *strLastpath = [strPath lastPathComponent];        
    NSString *folderName = [@"Object File/" stringByAppendingString:strLastpath];        
    NSLog(@"Path : %@ \n File Name : %@",strPath,folderName);        
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                       NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];        
    docsDir=[docsDir stringByAppendingString:@"/Object File"];        
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: 
                    [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName]];

    NSLog(@"Database Path : %@",databasePath);        
    NSError *theError = nil;       
    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    **//I added this line**
    [filemgr createDirectoryAtPath:docsDir 
       withIntermediateDirectories:YES 
                        attributes:nil 
                             error:&theError];

    **//Changed this line**
    [data writeToFile:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:strLastpath]            
              options:NSDataWritingAtomic  
                error:&theError];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:strLastpath]]){
        NSLog(@"File Exists");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File not exists");
        NSLog(@"Tell Me error %@",[theError localizedDescription]);
    }       
}
```